# How to do post request with dynamic data in date and time via xml

Tags: php, xml, drupal, automated-tests, behat

I wanted to do a post request in the form of XML , but thing is i don't want static data in date and time fields . I wanted to take today's date from system.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<site_banner>
    <title>Behat Test Banner</title>
    <type>site_banner</type>
    <language>en</language>
    <field_banner_message_str>
        <und is_array="true">
            <item>
                <value>Test please ignore</value>
            </item>
        </und>
    </field_banner_message_str>
    <field_banner_type>
        <und>
            <value>success</value>
        </und>
    </field_banner_type>
    <field_banner_start_date>
        <und is_array="true">
            <item>
                <value>
                    <date>06/01/2018</date>
                    <time>07:30:00</time>
                </value>
            </item>
        </und>
    </field_banner_start_date>
    <field_banner_end_date>
        <und is_array="true">
            <item>
                <value>
                    <date>06/01/2018</date>
                    <time>08:30:00</time>
                </value>
            </item>
        </und>
    </field_banner_end_date>
</site_banner>
```

This is the post call i am making , so is there any way we can make date and time dynamic according to system. I have tried including some code in JavaScript but did't work.
It will be great help, as i am quiet new to API automation.

Comment: Which system? User's or server? Where is this xml being sent from/to? Where and how is the xml generated?  Not really enough process flow given to help

Comment: System - RHEL. 
I am using postman to send request currently. 
I am trying to create a content in Drupal (i.e CMS),so while creating it need to provide the dynamic data as this code will be running by automation every time , so i have not to go and change every time date and time to make it work. I am trying to make run without manual intervention of caring about date and time

Comment: OK so this is response from a remote api and you want to modify it? Still a bit confusing

Comment: hmmm, i want to make post api dynamic , below fields. So every time post is made instead of manual date it will take system date. 
<date>06/01/2018</date>
 <time>07:30:00</time>

Comment: Are you generating this xml or is some other remote api service? You really haven't explained the whole process flow here

Comment: Yes, i am creating this xml .
So when we do a post api request in postman, we provide a xml/json so this is the same xml i am using to post some data on my site.
So what i am trying to do is do make this post api call run by automation using Behat (API automation framework).
So this post call is for creating a site banner , it displays on the site for certain amount of time i.e date and time i am providing.
When running automation i don't want static data in date and time as it will not be able to verify because date will be in past .So to make it dynamic can we do something?

Comment: Show how the xml is created then. This doesn't sound like a javascript issue but a php one

Comment: Well can we add JavaScript code for date to XML data to make it work dynamically?

Comment: But aren't you wanting to predetermine the date server side? Still quite confused about how this is all supposed to work. You should update question with all those details

Comment: Tip: [*ISO 8601*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: It depends on what tool you are using to perform the post request. If you automate with Behat, read Behat doc. Same with Postman (btw you can use variables and run test scripts right from Postman). You should use JSON instead of XML whenever you can.

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks ,
Behat script contains gherkin (As it is BDD based framework) , so what i am trying to do here is run this automated script not from postman , but by build that will run by Jenkins.
So hard coded dates are not acceptable as start date and end date are passed by XML data i am providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have been trying to solve this issue and found out we change the node data in XML.

```
<field_banner_start_date>
        <und is_array="true">
            <item>
                <value>
                    <date>$STARTDATE</date>
                    <time>$STARTTIME</time>
                </value>
            </item>
        </und>
    </field_banner_start_date>

if (strpos($node_data, '$STARTDATE') !== FALSE) {
     $node_data = str_replace('$STARTDATE', date('m/d/Y'), $node_data);  
}
```

So now here every time whne this code will run it will override node data of $STARTDATE to today's date and time.

Thanks for replying on my question! If this helps anybody i am glad!